# PandasのDataFrameから、整数・浮動小数に変換可能な行を抽出するには

Tags: python, python3, pandas

PandasのDataFrameで、文字列型の列から、整数や浮動小数に変換可能な値をもつ行を抽出する方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？
Seriesの `str.isidigit()` などを利用することで、次のように整数に変換可能な行は抽出できました。
さらに小数に型変換可能かどうか判定するには、どのようにしたらよいでしょうか。

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    {'aa': 'エラー', 'bb': 'BB01'},
    {'aa': '10.5', 'bb': 'BB02'},
    {'aa': '20', 'bb': 'BB02'},
])
display('入力')
display(df.info())
display(df)

display('出力')
df_out = df[df['aa'].str.isdigit()]
display(df_out)

display('期待する結果')
df_expected = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    {'aa': '10.5', 'bb': 'BB02'},
    {'aa': '20', 'bb': 'BB02'},
])
display(df_expected)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

なおPythonの標準機能では、文字列から小数に変換可能かどうか判定することは困難なようでした。
https://neko-py.com/python-type-judge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
>>> df[df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').notna().any(axis=1)]
     aa    bb
1  10.5  BB02
2    20  BB02
```

Comment: df_expected = df[df['aa'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').notna()]  ありがとうございます。期待通りの結果が得られました。